# Django Join two models

Tags: python, django

I'm beginner to Django. I want to ask how can I get the addresses of all the Dials that are in DataUpload table from BO table. It doesn't return any data in Customer_Address column in HTML.

```
class DataUpload(models.Model):
    Dial = models.IntegerField()

    Customer_Address = models.ForeignKey(BO, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    null=True,blank=True, related_name='address')

    National_ID = models.IntegerField()
    Customer_ID = models.IntegerField()
    Status = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Registration_Date = models.DateTimeField(max_length=100)
    Is_Documented = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
```

BO Model:

```
class BO(models.Model):
   id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   Dial = models.IntegerField()
   Customer_Address = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
   Wallet_Limit_profile = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
```

View:

```
def listing(request):    
data = DataUpload.objects.all()


paginator = Paginator(data, 10) # Show 25 contacts per page.
page_number = request.GET.get('page')
paged_listing = paginator.get_page(page_number)
# print(data)
return render(request, 'pages/listing.html', {'paged_listing': paged_listing, 'range': range})
```

When I call item.Customer_Address it does return any data and no errors are appearing, also I tried item.Customer_Address_id.Customer_Address same thing.
HTML:

```
            {% for item in paged_listing %}
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center align-middle">{{ item.Dial }}</td>
                <td class="text-center align-middle">{{ item.Customer_Address}}</td>
                <td class="text-center align-middle">{{ item.National_ID }}</td>
                <td class="text-center align-middle">{{ item.Status }}</td>-->
                <!-- <td><a href="{% url 'edit_record' item.Dial %}">Edit</a> </td> -->
                <td class="text-center  align-middle"> <button class="btn btn-primary"><a class="edit-link"
                    href="{% url 'edit_record' item.id %}">Edit</button> </a> </td>

            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Try `item.Customer_Address.Customer_Address `

Comment: Hi I have tried this but I got this error  Field 'id' expected a number but got ''.

Comment: Are you want to get the customer's address or something else?

Comment: Yes I'm trying to get the customer's address but i'm facing the mentioned error